# Calculate mean over keys of dict with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, mean

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
mydict = {0: [1, 2, 3],
          1: [10, 20, 30],
          2: [100, 200, 300]}
```

I want to calculate the mean of index 1 of all three entries of the dict. 
My first intention was to do:

```
mean_value = np.mean(mydict[:][1])
```

but this gives me

> "TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'.

Well, ok, that makes sense. But why can't I do:

```
mean_value = np.array(mydict[i][1] for i in range(3)).mean()
```

or

```
mean_value = np.mean(mydict[i][1] for i in range(3))
```

The expected output would be "74" as in (2+20+200)/3. But I get

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'

Answer (score 2):

`mean` doesn't accept a generator, but could accept a list:

```py
mean_value = np.mean([mydict[i][1] for i in range(3)])
# Note the squares --^------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

`average = (mean(list(mydict.keys())))` is a very concise and pythonic way to get the mean of dictionary key. It also avoids using a list comprehension which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `list` the `values()` from the dictionary and then do a mean. You can directly get the mean at `index 1` as,

```
np.mean(list(mydict.values()),0)[1]
```